# how to restrict `like` operator in query to start with something

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query that title start with A or B

is this correct?
**I dont want use `OR`**

I want use it in mysql ,

```
    select * from table where title like `[AB]%`
```

Comment: You want only `like`?

Comment: @AlmaDo no , but I want be short

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like

```
select * from table where title like `A%` OR title like `B%`
```

another way is to use regular expression

```
select * from table where title REGEXP  '^(A|B)';
```

Comment: It return me error ` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where title REGEXP '^(A|B)' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2``

Comment: what $sql you are using in your phpmyadmin. is "table" is your table name???. if yes then add it inside backticks

Comment: select * from "`table`"  where title REGEXP  '^(A|B)'; try this. i tried with my db table and it worked

Comment: I want use it in mysql

Answer (score 3):

Use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE title REGEXP '^[AB]'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a9a36/2)

Or just use a substring:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE LEFT(title, 1) IN ('A', 'B');
```

Comment: Oops, typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @zhilevan If the table is large you should take care to compare the execution plans of these with that of `title like 'A%' OR title like 'B%'`. Two index range scans are probably faster than a full index scan.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Very good point. Usually `OR` prevents indexing, but not in this case because they're both accessing the same column.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEX '^[AB]'

Comment: I fixed that typo over an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct way:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE 'A%' or title LIKE 'B%';`

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote should work. or you can use, 
select * 
from table_name
where title LIKE 'A%' OR title LIKE 'B%'

Comment: No, it shouldn't work. There are some databases that allow that type of matching with `LIKE` (I think SQL-Server), but not MySQL.

Comment: select * from table where title like `[A-B]%`
I have seen this thing working some places

Comment: Maybe it was `RLIKE`, which is a synonym for `REGEXP`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `LIKE` operator in SQL only supports a limited syntax. It doesn't support a regex style syntax.

You have to do divide it into two expressions:

```
select * from table where (title like 'A%' or title like 'B%')
```

Note:

In this case the parenthesis are superfluous, but since `OR` has a lower precedence than `AND` I think it is good practice to routinely add parenthesis around `OR`expressions in SQL.

Comment: `REGEXP` has a richer search vocabulary, so don't be afraid to use `REGEXP` instead.